# Why is the Raleway font not working on my site?

Tags: fonts

Raleway font was being used on this site and I tried to change it to Lato.  Lato didn't work for some reason - it ended up looking like Times Roman - so I want to change it back to Raleway.  I have changed the CSS and the enqueue fonts script back to the original but when I look at the site and inspect element Lato still shows up.  Here is the enqueue script:

```
// add Google Fonts//
function wpse_google_webfonts() {
$protocol = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';
$query_args = array(
    'family' => 'Raleway',
    'subset' => 'latin,latin-ext',
);

wp_enqueue_style('google-webfonts',
    add_query_arg($query_args, "$protocol://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Raleway" ),
    array(), null);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_google_webfonts' );
```

Is something wrong with this?  It is the original script that was being used.  If you want to look at the site it is https://www.classtechtips.com and you can see all the font is Lato.  How do I get this to change? It says it is still in the CSS but I changed it and for some reason it is not being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

I just visited the site with Firefox inspector, and I see the CSS style enqueued correctly and the `Raleway` font being downloaded.

Checking the css for body I can see that the `app.css`, for the body tag, still specifies `Lato` as the font.

Perhaps you missed changing that back, or if using a cache plugin, perhaps you need to flush it.

By the way next time add `Wordpress` to the question's tags